# What's appropriate hardware for getting started with UNIX network programming?

Tags: networking, unix, hardware-rec

I'm interested in learning more about UNIX networking (socket programming etc). I prefer to use FreeBSD. **What's appropriate computer hardware to purchase and get started on?**

I know this is a basic question :-) Any help is appreciated since I've been working on Mac and Windows boxes for my entire life.

Comment: Any? I don't think you'll run into problems. The list of [Ethernet devices](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/8.2R/hardware.html#ETHERNET) supported by FreeBSD is quite long.

Comment: You do realize that your Mac *is* a Unix system, that happens to have a fancy GUI?

Comment: @DanielBeck yes I realize that. I'd like a dedicated *nix box that I can use to talk to my other computers (network programming etc).

Answer (score 4):

A computer, Pentium Pro or better, and a network card (any built-in to the system should be acceptable).

Answer (score 2):

My only caveat would be to avoid wireless cards if possible. Fewer are supported, and wireless connections always break more often than ethernet regardless of the OS.